# rxjs/Subscription undefined value of another subscription

Tags: rxjs

I need to use the value of another subscription into a subscription. Here is the code. Product value is undefined, what is the best method to access the value?

Code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'product-page',
    templateUrl: 'product-page.html'
})
export class ProductPage {
    private product: Product;
    this.store.select('products').subscribe(({
        product
    }) => {
        if (product) {
            this.product = product;
        }
    });
    this.store.select('plc').subscribe((value: any) = > {
        console.log(this.product); // undefined
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine to two selections using the [`combineLatest` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest):

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';
// ...

this.store
  .select('products')
  .combineLatest(this.store.select('plc'))
  .subscribe(([products, plc]) => {
    // ...
  });
```